# Moving old project to newer versions

Tags: blackberry

I am new to Blackberry. Present I am working on 4.7 Blackberry component pack.Now I want to move my old projects to newer versions like 5.0 and 6.0. For that I installed eclipse Galileo 3.5 version and configured latest component packs and Blackberry java plug_in 1.1.2.
  I searched in google and find somewhere that use File menu option Import>Import Legacy Blackberry projects and it is  asking .jdw file in the workspace.I dont want to move entire workspace, I want only single project. am not able to find it.can any one help me to get this......

Comment: select the .jdw file and check the option "copy blackberry projects into workspace" for more information.
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Import_BB_app_from_BBJDE_workspace_655907_11.jsp

Comment: of course, but when I select the previous workspace it didn't show any .jdw files that is what I frustrated..The folder contains some previous projects..How can I recognize the .jdw file while browse for it..

Comment: Thanks I can move the old projects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, for your old project, try to compile with the new JDE like say 5.0. See what breaks, fix it, repeat till it compiles. Then run on handset to ensure it looks ok.

Comment: Instead I moving from old workspace I checked out from svn to the eclipse but it is not showing Blackberry_app_Descriptor.xml and showing all errors. I found in the properties of the project Builders showing Missing Builders say net.rim.eide.ResourceBuilder...what to do?

Comment: One thing to try is to get the old code compile on Eclipse with its old JDE, that will make sure everything is set up correctly. Then set JDE to 5.0 and try compiling and work out the errors

Comment: Remember to Refresh and "Clean" for your project.

Comment: I checked out the project from svn eclipse 3.5 version. In run configurations  of the project in the Project tab it is not showing the concerned running project with checkbox and all the code showing errors which is in the 4.7 version...